# Understanding the initialisation of a variable of particular type

Tags: go

How is the below initialisation happening?

tT me it looks like test is behaving more like a function.. taking an argument and return the same.

I know its very basic, but i cant figure it out what is happening here. a little explanation would be helpful. Is this some kind of shortcut notation for assignment and initialisation in single line?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type test int

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test(20))
}
```

Comment: The expression `T(x)` is a type conversion. `test(20)` converts the untyped integer constant `20` to type `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no variables in the quoted code. There is a type, `test`, whose underlying type is `int`. What you see "behaving like a function" is a type conversion from the literal `20` to the type `test`.

I highly recommend taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org), which covers all the language basics with examples and explanations and only takes a few minutes. In particular, pay attention to the section on types and [type conversions](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13).